# Android Http Post to MySQL Database

Tags: php, android, mysql, http-post

in my App i have a function to send a new Spot plus information to my MySQL.
It works everythink fine so far, but if anyone write a longer text in the editText fields, i get no entry in my Database.

Here a code snippet from the sendactivity in the App:

```
private class NewSpotOperation extends AsyncTask<Spot, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Spot... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("Server URL");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        try {

            // JSON data:
            json.put("Longitude", params[0].getLongitude());
            json.put("Latitude", params[0].getLatitude());
            json.put("Name", params[0].getName());
            json.put("Bestand", params[0].getBestand());
            json.put("Inhaber", params[0].getInhaber());
            json.put("Bezugsorte", params[0].getBezugsorte());
            json.put("Groesse", params[0].getGroesse());
            json.put("Infos", params[0].getInfos());
            json.put("Preise", params[0].getPreise());

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

            httppost.setEntity(se);
            httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            if(response != null)
            {......
```

Then it will be send to my PHP on my Webspace:

```
        case "POST":
        $params = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), false);
        $stmc = $dbh->prepare("insert into angelspots (Longitude, Latitude, Name, Bestand, Inhaber, Bezugsorte, Groesse, Infos,  Preise) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmc->bindParam(1, $params->Longitude);
        $stmc->bindParam(2, $params->Latitude);
        $stmc->bindParam(3, $params->Name);
        $stmc->bindParam(4, $params->Bestand);
        $stmc->bindParam(5, $params->Inhaber);
        $stmc->bindParam(6, $params->Bezugsorte);
        $stmc->bindParam(7, $params->Groesse);
        $stmc->bindParam(8, $params->Infos);
        $stmc->bindParam(9, $params->Preise);
        $stmc->execute();

        break;
} } catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Fehler: ".$e->getMessage();
die(); }
```

I try to find a solution in the last 5 days but i dont know whats the problem.
Maybe someone can help me and say me whats wrong to send more than only a few words in my databse.

best greetings and thank you!

Comment: what is size of column of that table which is not inserted. Check size with input.

Comment: BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent())); String msg=""; String line = ""; while ((line = bufferreader.readLine()) != null) { msg += line; } Log.i("msg=",""+msg);

Comment: Put the above code after  'HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);' and tell me what msg are u getting?

Comment: Thank you Exception i try it. If i fill "Lat" and "Lon", "Name": Stichkanal Golm, "Inhaber": Kreisanglerverband Potsdam-Land e.V. DAV Brandenburg, and "Infos": Wasserfahrzeuge verboten, it works and i have an Entry in my Database. But if i fill the same in the fields plus the field "Bestand": Aal, Forellen, Lachsforelle , Goldforelle, Saibling, Karpfen, Stör, Wels. It doesnt put in the Database.

Comment: Try simulate the query you are trying without an android app. Mostly as Code Lord mentioned, it could be because of size.

Comment: if i put it in my Database: INSERT INTO `dbxxxxxxx`.`angelspots` (`Id`, `Longitude`, `Latitude`, `Confirmed`, `Name`, `Bestand`, `Inhaber`, `Bezugsorte`, `Groesse`, `Infos`, `Preise`) VALUES (NULL, '12.456546', '54.568756', '0', 'Stichkanal Golm', 'Aal, Forellen, Lachsforelle , Goldforelle, Saibling, Karpfen, Stör, Wels', 'Kreisanglerverband Potsdam-Land e.V. DAV Brandenburg', '', '', 'Wasserfahrzeuge verboten', ''); It works without any problems. It works from my Tablet too, but Users with other phones have problems to send the same Infos in the App.